# Erro de Redirecionamento de Página -URL

Tags: django

Sou super iniciante com `Python` e `Django` e infelizmente estou sofrendo bastante com `urls`. O problema que dá é de "`Página não encontrada (404)`". Segue abaixo trechos do código:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import web.views
urlpatterns = [

    #url(r'^$/', 'web.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^web/', 'views.index'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect # Funcao para redirecionar o usuario
#Criar as Views aqui

# pagina inicial do projeto dweb
def index(request):
    return render_to_response("index.html")
```

Comment: Você está usando `DEBUG = True` no `settings.py`? Qual URL está dando esse erro? Se seu servidor está executando por exemplo em `localhost:8000` (o padrão do `runserver`) então a única página que deverá estar disponível - pelas regras do seu `urls.py` - é a `http://localhost:8000/web/`. É essa URL que está dando 404? Ou é outra?

Comment: Olá Earendul, Bom Dia!!... Sim, estou usando o DEBUG = True. Esta é a url q está dando erro:  url(r'^web/', 'views.index'), mesmo eu adicionando essa url. Ele me redireciona para essa: http://127.0.0.1:8000/. Aí dá o erro!!

Comment: Esse `views.index` não deveria ser `web.views.index`?

Comment: Olá  mgibsonbr, boa tarde!!... Consegui resolver mais de outra forma, veja o que postei agora! Mas essa pergunta que vc me fez está corretíssima, seria isso mesmo no caso anterior!!... Obrigada :)!!

Answer (score 1):

fazendo algumas pesquisas consegui resolver esse problema de outra forma. Mas desde já agradeço pela ajuda de todos! Vejam abaixo como ficou:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns,include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/',include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'web.views.homepage', name="index"),

]
```

views.py

```
__author__ = 'Sara Fernandes'

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

#from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect # Funcao para redirecionar o usuario
#Criar as Views aqui

# pagina inicial do projeto dweb

def homepage(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html',
        context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```